# Possible to auto populate Lync clients with default contacts

Tags: lync, lync-2013

We are rolling out Lync and one request was to push out (and perhaps update) contacts to end users.

Is this feature possible in Lync?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any official tool for this.  MS treats Lync just like Outlook in that there is a "global address list" you can search but contacts are like Outlook contacts, added per account.

However, there is a developed tool to handle this:

https://lumt.codeplex.com/

Now...I've never had to use it, but I bookmarked it just in case we ever went down this path.

NOTE:  Just because you got this request I would really vet it out with folks on which contacts you are wanting to "push".  It may seem like a good idea but most of the time it's better to let people add their own contacts as needed.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't make it clear if it is for Lync Online or Lync on-premises.

For Lync On-premises, LUMT is a good solution, but it simply doesn't work for Lync Online.

For Lync Online (which is part of an Office 365 subscription - and by the way, Lync was re-branded as Skype for Business by Microsoft, so we should rather say Skype for Business Online), there are only two options available :

- The contacts manager from Vytru
- The SfB online contact manager from Express-Desk, which is offered as a freeware via:
  http://support.express-desk.com/support/Skype-for-Business-Online-Contact-Manager

Answer (score 0):

One of the tools we are considering is to be used in a way that we load up employees with a specific contact list. We have not attempted to utilize this in production as of yet, as the price is a little steep but depending on the budget this might be a viable option.

http://www.vytru.com/contacts-manager

Answer (score -1):

Contacts Manger software from Vytru, a tool for building up contact list with normal or Distribution Groups and then you can auto populate the pre-configured Contact List to your staff.

or you can Export the Contact Lit from Skype for Business or Lync client and then auto pouplate it to your end users.

Later on you can delete or add new contact if needed.

http://www.vytru.com/contacts-manager-for-microsoft-lync-skype-for-business.html